# Getting rid of white space in image gallery

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys im not sure if this is the correct term but im building an image gallery in bootstrap with the idea of using masonry, so basically , everything is in different sizes , my problem is i have a huge gap in between my gallreys and i was wondering how i can get rid of it. My problem looks like this : 
[image]

I would like it so that space in the red circle could go away and that , i could connect them together

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x600" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x700" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x600" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x300" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/500x700" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if there is an easier way of doing this, im using boostrap 3 or if im doing something stupid but i would like to build a gallery using this idea but just so i can get rid of those big spaces

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use multiple row, that makes it impossible to avoid that gaps. All you have to do is, there will be only one row in the entire page, but multiple column. Then there will be no gap. A pseudo code is as follows:

```
<div class=row>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

         images 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

         images 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

         images 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

         images 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">

         images 
    </div>
 <div>
```

Comment: I sort of understand, but how would this work with my code that i put up there, could u show me a fiddle , because i tried 2 do it, but i cant seem to get it to work at all

Comment: Sorry I cannot create fiddle at this point as I am in remote and using my mobile device to answer. However, ideally you should able to put the cards inside the columns. I did similar things before in http://dev.mycake.city . You can check the HTML there.